# while[1 -le1000]:command not found

Tags: mysql, linux

this shell can run successfully,and the mysql  added a record

```
#!/bin/nash
i=1;
mysql -uroot -p123456 test -e"insert into user(username,gender,birthday)   values('hello$i','man',NOW());"
exit 0
```

but when i want to insert into mysql data largely,in shell i add the while and do ,it whill remind error

```
#!/bin/nash
 i=1;
 while[$i -le 1000]
do
mysql -uroot -p123456 test -e"insert into user(username,gender,birthday)    values('hello$i','man',NOW());"
let i=i+1
sleep 0.01
down
exit 0
```

it will appear like this

```
./insert.sh:line 3:while[1- le 1000]:command not found
./insert.sh:line 4:syntax error near unexpected token 'do'
./insert.sh:line 4:'do'
```

Comment: you're missing a space between "1000" and "]"

Comment: The spacing is important - see http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html - for a simple example.

Comment: ^ That. FYI, `[` is a standalone command rather than shell syntax.

Comment: thank you  ,the problem have solved